# how to fix swagger-ui path

Tags: spring-boot, openapi-generator, springdoc-openapi-ui

There was a problem with the Swagger document path.

build.gradle
`implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.8")`

application.properties
`server.servlet.context-path: /poo`

REQ : http://localhost:port/poo/swagger-ui/index.html
-> Failed to load remote configuration.

REQ : http://localhost:port/poo//swagger-ui/index.html
-> OK

Answer (score 0):

Can be Ingress, try this

Change this

```
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /my-context/my-path/swagger
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-service #.ns-config.svc.cluster.local
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

For this

```
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: my-service #.ns-config.svc.cluster.local
                port:
                  number: 8080
            path: /my-context/my-path/swagger
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

Answer (score 0):

Might check this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73504834/10978688) describing the best approach to using `spring-doc` behind custom `context-path` or `proxy`.