# No API definition provided with springdoc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, springdoc

I am using springdoc 1.6.9 with spring boot 2.6.9

I need to load swagger-ui after the service name so i have added below,

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    config-url: /myservice/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
    path: /myservice/swagger-ui/index.html
    disable-swagger-default-url: true
  api-docs:
    path: /myservice/v3/api-docs
```

I also have below in security config,

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").
               .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html").antMatchers("/myservice/swagger-ui/**")
               .antMatchers("myservice/v3/api-docs/**");
    }
```

When i locally start the service and access `http://localhost:8080/myservice/v3/api-docs`, it successfully return api spec in json format.

But when i access swagger ui as defined in the property file as
`http://localhost:8080/myservice/swagger-ui/index.html` it redirect to `http://localhost:8080/myservice/swagger-ui/swagger-ui/index.html` and shows `No API definition provided.`

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your security config you missing first (/):
`.... .antMatchers("/myservice/v3/api-docs/**")`

And for properties try to use this one:

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    config-url: /myservice/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
    path: /myservice/swagger-ui.html
    url: ${springdoc.api-docs.path}
    disable-swagger-default-url: true
  api-docs:
    path: /myservice/v3/api-docs
```

Comment: Even without the antMatchers by using above springdoc config it works

Comment: This worked for me. It should also be configUrl